# How to express other logical operations via Pierce's arrow?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

x↑y, x⇒y, and x⇔y. So I have really given my best, but all I could do is express the conjunction, disjunction, negation, and impilcation.

Comment: See [Logical NOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_NOR)

Comment: Pierce Arrow is an automobile company. Car companies were never known as particularly logical.

Comment: If you need more, you have to note that $x⇔y$ is $(x⇒y) \land (y⇒x)$ and that for [NAND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke) $x↑y$ is $\lnot (x \land y)$.

Comment: The second comment is funny. How come you never heard of of the pierce arrow, it's basically the nor operator? I have already written implication, conjunction and disjunction via the pierce arrow, but the ones I noted in the description are giving me a hard time.

Comment: I heard of Peirce's arrow. But Pierce Arrow? That's a different thing altogether.

Comment: @AER - why you decided that the original question regarding NOR (Peirce's arrow) was "really" intended to mean NAND (Sheffer's stroke) ?

Comment: Wait, I can't remember having it changed from NOR to NAND. Anyway, it's fixed now, and I have come to the correct solutions.Thank you all.

Comment: @Shemafied - please note again that it is **Peirce's arrow**, from the philosopher and logician [Charles Sanders Peirce](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/peirce/) and **not** Pierce's arrow ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complement to the comments above.

It suffices to note that:

$\neg$:

$\ $ $\ $ $\ $ $\ $$\neg \varphi \Leftrightarrow \varphi \uparrow \varphi$

$\wedge$:

$\ $ $\ $ $\ $ $\ $$\varphi \wedge \psi \Leftrightarrow  (\varphi \uparrow \varphi) \uparrow (\psi \uparrow \psi)$

Now how to proceed to the others connectives? Since we already have $\neg$ and $\wedge$ we can proceed by translating them in some of the well-knwon standard equivalences:

$\vee$:

$\ $ $\ $ $\ $ $\ $$\varphi \vee \psi \Leftrightarrow \neg(\neg \varphi \wedge \neg \psi) \Leftrightarrow$ (and so on)

Answer (score 1):

Write the other operations in terms of implication, conjunction, and disjunction, and then replace the implications, conjunctions, and disjunctions with formulas you already have that involve only the arrow operator.